# Assign a Static Public IP to Istio ingress-gateway Loadbalancer service

Tags: istio, azure-aks, static-ip-address, azure-load-balancer

As you know by installing Istio, it creates a kubernetes loadbalancer with a publicIP and use the public IP as External IP of istio-ingress-gateway LoadBalancer service. As the IP is not Static, I have created a static public IP in Azure which is in the same ResourceGroup as AKS, I found the resource-group name as below:

```
 $ az aks show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster --query nodeResourceGroup -o tsv
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip

I download the installation file through following command:

```
curl -L https://git.io/getLatestIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.4.2 sh -
```

I tried to re-install istio by following command:

```
$ helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system --set grafana.enabled=true --set prometheus.enabled=true --set tracing.enabled=true --set kiali.enabled=true --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerIP= my-static-public-ip | kubectl apply -f -
```

However it didn't work, still got the dynamic IP. So I tried to setup my static public IP on the files:
istio-demo.yaml, istio-demo-auth.yaml by adding loadbalancer IP under istio-ingressgateway:

```
spec:
type: LoadBalancer
loadBalancerIP: my-staticPublicIP
```

Also file: values-istio-gteways.yaml

```
 loadBalancerIP: "mystaticPublicIP"
 externalIPs: ["mystaticPublicIP"]
```

And then re-installed the istio using helm command as it mentioned above. This time it added mystaticPublicIP as one of the External_IP of istio-ingress-gateway Loadbalancer service. So now it has both dynamic IP and mystaticPublicIP.
That doesn't seem a right way to do that.

I went through the relevant questions under this website and also googled but none of them could help.

I'm wondering if anyone know how to make this work out?

Comment: Based on documentation I could not find anything about that, only [that](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#why-use-istio), istio provide Automatic load balancing for HTTP, gRPC, WebSocket, and TCP traffic. I think workaround might be loadbalancer in azure,then configure it to point to the cluster istio-ingressgateway loadbalancer ip.

Answer (score 2):

I can successfully assign the static public IP to Istio gateway service with the following command,

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm --name istio --namespace istio-system --set gateways.istio-ingressgateway.loadBalancerIP=my-static-public-ip | kubectl apply -f –
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. so you used helm template install/kubernetes/helm instead of helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio ?